# C++ is overloading my overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I noticed something today. If I create three versions of an overloaded + operators to handle every combination ( object + primitive, primitive + object, object + object) everything executes as expected:

```
class Int
{ int data;
  public:  
    Int (){data = 0; };
    Int (int size){ data = size; };
    friend int operator+(Int, Int);
    friend int operator+(int, Int);
    friend int operator+(Int, int);
};
int operator+(Int lInt, Int rInt) 
{   cout <<"first version. "; 
    return rInt.data + lInt.data; 
}
int operator+(int lInt, Int rInt) 
{   cout <<"second version. "; 
    return rInt.data + lInt; 
}
int operator+(Int lInt, int rInt)
{   cout <<"third version. ";
    return lInt.data + rInt;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Int int1 = 1;

    cout <<  int1 + int1 <<endl; // prints "first version. 2"
    cout <<  3 + int1 << endl;   // prints "second version. 4"
    cout <<  int1 + 3 << endl;   // prints "third version. 4"
}
```

But if I delete the second and third versions it still works!?!

```
class Int
{ int data;
  public:  
    Int (){data = 0; };
    Int (int size){ data = size; };
    friend int operator+(Int, Int);
};
int operator+(Int lInt, Int rInt) 
{   cout <<"first version. "; 
    return rInt.data + lInt.data; 
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Int int1 = 1;

    cout <<  int1 + int1 <<endl; // prints "first version. 2"
    cout <<  3 + int1 << endl;   // prints "first version. 4"
    cout <<  int1 + 3 << endl;   // prints "first version. 4"
}
```

How is my overloaded + operator, which is meant to accept two objects, able to take an int and object. How is it able to take object and an int? I hope I'm not overlooking something stupidly obvious here!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this guy:

```
Int (int size){ data = size; };
```

Since it is not marked [`explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean), that is an implicit constructor, and the compiler will automatically shove a call to it in contexts where you have an `int` but a function (or operator) is expecting an `Int`.

So, for example, the compiler resolves

```
cout <<  3 + int1 << endl;
```

to

```
cout <<  Int(3) + int1 << endl;
```

automatically.

It is often a good idea to use the `explicit` keyword to force this kind of code to be more explicit, however, it should be mentioned that implicit construction is heavily used in very prominent code, most notably the C++ Standard Library, where, for example, a `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from a `const char*`. It's a tradeoff between convenience and clarity.

Comment: Thanks to you too. Now I understand!

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an implicit conversion from `int` to `Int`:

```
Int (int size){ data = size; };
```

So the compiler can figure out that `Int + int` should call `Int + Int(int)`.

If you didn't want that, for whatever reason, you would mark the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: AHH! I see! But if a constructor has no return value how is std::cout getting the answer?

Comment: @Jeff-Russ: The "return value" of a constructor is the constructed object. And the argument to `<<` is the result of `operator+(Int, Int)`, whose value is an `int`, not an `Int`.